# Regular Expression in php, compilation failed

Tags: php, regex

```
$string = '/product/list.html?a=b';
$regex = '#^^/(?P[\w]+)/(?P[\w]+)(?P[^\.]*)\.*(?P[html|xml|json]*)(?P[\?.*]*)$$#';
$count = preg_match($regex, $string, $matches);
```

When i run above code, it raises this warning:

```
Warning: preg_match(): Compilation failed: unrecognized character after (?P at offset 6 in php shell code on line 1
```

I couldn't see where is the problem?

Comment: shouldn't it be `(?:P`...?

Comment: @anubhava because the component which i use includes those. I can only insert expressions in (?P and )

Comment: Provide sample input. If you are matching those characters then they need to be escaped.

Comment: Try escaping them .. `$regex = '#^^/(\?P[\w]+)/(\?P[\w]+)(\?P[^\.]*)\.*(\?P[html|xml|json]*)(\?P[\?.*]*)$$#';`

Comment: What is `?P[\w]` supposed to do?

Comment: Lets start at what must it match? Meaning, what do you want it to do?

Comment: @Raphioly-San i want to create a general url pattern to match url to controller, action, query etc.

Comment: Maybe you meant something like [this](http://regex101.com/r/pQ9uD9)?

Comment: @Jerry using (?:\?|.)* made it works! Thanks!

Comment: @sedatsevgili I changed much more than that though... Well, I still don't get your 'component' =/ Oh well.

Answer (score 0):

`(?P` is used to start a [*named capturing group*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/named.html). The syntax is:

```
(?P<name>regexp)
```

When you use this syntax, the part of the string that matches the regexp will be found in `$matches['name']`.

You're missing `<name>` from your regexp.

Comment: Thanks for your help but i could not include the <name> part because of component i used. However [Jerry](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22531637/regular-expression-in-php-compilation-failed?noredirect=1#comment34287502_22531637) helped :)

Answer (score 0):

New solution ;)

This works as: //someurl/index.php/controller/action

```
    if (array_key_exists('PATH_INFO', $_SERVER)) {
        $parts = explode('/', trim($_SERVER['PATH_INFO'], ' /'));

        @list($controller, $action) = $parts;
        $params = array_slice($parts, 2);

        $controller = empty($controller) ? 'default' : ucfirst(strtolower($controller));
        $action = empty($action) ? 'default' : strtolower($action);
    } else {
        $params = array();
        $controller = 'default';
        $action = 'default';
    }
```

Wouldn't this be more simple? (Change 'default' into anything you desire)

Answer (score 0):

Your regex seems a little bit wrong, maybe you were trying to get this:

```
#^/(?P<folder>[\w]+)/(?P<name>[\w]+)\.(?P<ext>html|xml|json)\?(?P<query>.*)$#
```

[Example](https://xrg.es/#1ryn5oq)

Result:

```
0 -> /product/list.html?a=b
folder -> product
name -> list
ext -> html
query -> a=b
```